# firebird - codeigniter connection

Tags: php, codeigniter, firebird, firebird2.1

i just moved my project from my laptop to the local server, which is Linux Fedora.
my project was working fine when i run it on my laptop
but when i moved it to the local server
it gave me this error.

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: core/Loader.php
>
> Line Number: 338

i tried using native php ibase_connect
and it's throwing this error

> Unable to complete network request to host "192.168.4.141". Failed to
>   establish a connection. in /var/www/html/connect_firebird.php

here's the db setting in config/database.php file

```
$db['sdisdb']['hostname'] = "192.168.4.141";
$db['sdisdb']['username'] = "sysdba";
$db['sdisdb']['password'] = "masterkey";    
$db['sdisdb']['database'] = "D:\path\to\database.fdb";
$db['sdisdb']['dbdriver'] = "firebird";
$db['sdisdb']['port']    = 3050;
$db['sdisdb']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['sdisdb']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['sdisdb']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['sdisdb']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['sdisdb']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['sdisdb']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['sdisdb']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

anything wrong with my config?

Comment: The error usually indicates that the Firebird server is not responding on that IP address. Make sure that 1) Firebird is running, 2) is running on port 3050, 3) that it is bound on that IP address (in a lot of Linux deployments Firebird is by default only bound on 127.0.0.1) and 4) that the firewall is allowing access to that port.

Comment: problem no.1 firebird is running, problem no 2, it is running on port 3050, problem no.3 i have no idea check whether it's bound or not 4, firewall is allowing acces to that port

Comment: You could check with `netstat` on which address it is listening (`0.0.0.0` indicates it is bound to all addresses), or you could try to telnet from a remote computer to the server on port 3050. If the connection is accepted (no error), then it is listening. If on linux, you probably need to look at the `(x)inetd.conf` to check on which address(es) the service is bound.

Comment: i tried using netsat -an | grep 3050 |grep LISTEN, and it returned tcp 0 0.0.0.0:3050 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN

Comment: Can you telnet from the PHP server to the firebird server on port 3050?

Comment: tried this telnet 192.168.4.141 3050 it returned "trying to connect 192.168.4.141... connected to 192.168.5.141. escape character is '^]'"

Comment: Then I see no obvious reason why it isn't able to connect.

Comment: does that mean it is able to connect to the firebird server, but something's still blocking the access which is you don't know? thanks for your time answering my questions anyway

Answer (score 0):

the value of this

```
$db['sdisdb']['database'] = "D:\path\to\database.fdb";
```

should be database name

Comment: oh, thanks for the response, i tried to change that line using the database alias, but..didn't work

Comment: getting same error? also does your database is on same server or on remote server

Comment: remote server.. oh i forgot to mention that i use 2 separate database

Comment: 2 separate database? means you are connecting to 2 databases or your files are hosted on one server and database is on another server(192.168.4.141)?

Comment: yes, the firebird is on my laptop because it's still in testing environment

Comment: you need to add the Access host(files server) with its username and password with required privileges to your database servers "user" table

Comment: @PravinS Firebird is a database server, you don't need to arrange file access to the database for the webserver.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel files server, i mean to say the server on which files are uploaded not the database server

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Codeigniter version 3
application/config/database.php

```
$db['firebird'] = array(
        'dsn'   => '',
        'hostname' => 'localhost',
        'username' => 'sysdba',
        'password' => 'masterkey',
        'database' => 'C://database.GDB',
        'dbdriver' => 'ibase',
        'dbprefix' => '',
        'pconnect' => FALSE,
        'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
        'cache_on' => FALSE,
        'cachedir' => '',
        'char_set' => 'ANSI',
        'dbcollat' => 'NONE',
        'swap_pre' => '',
        'encrypt' => FALSE,
        'compress' => FALSE,
        'stricton' => FALSE,
        'failover' => array(),
        'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```