# Codeigniter not able to connect to firebird

Tags: php, codeigniter, firebird

I have seen and tried all the solutions in [Codeigniter - multiple database connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619711/codeigniter-multiple-database-connections), [You have specified an invalid database connection group codeigniter error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309468/you-have-specified-an-invalid-database-connection-group-codeigniter-error), [firebird - codeigniter connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22630271/firebird-codeigniter-connection) and none of them worked.

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'testing';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;


$db['fbird']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['fbird']['username'] = "SYSDBA";
$db['fbird']['password'] = "masterkey";    
$db['fbird']['database'] = "C:\waitkyl.fdb";
$db['fbird']['dbdriver'] = "firebird";
```

After this configuration, I call the `fbird` database this way:

```
class Fb_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getAll(){
        $db = $this->load->database('fbird', TRUE);

        return $db->get('categories')->result();    
    }
}
```

And the error I get after trying output the values `print_r($this->fb_model->getAll());` is:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object

That usually means that the table 'categories' doesn't exists..which isn't true.

So I have tried to change my configuration file into:

```
$db['fbird']['hostname'] = "localhost";
$db['fbird']['username'] = "SYSDBA";
$db['fbird']['password'] = "masterkey";    
$db['fbird']['database'] = "C:\waitkyl.fdb";
$db['fbird']['dbdriver'] = "firebird";
$db['fbird']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['fbird']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['fbird']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['fbird']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['fbird']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['fbird']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['fbird']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```

And also removed from the `php.ini` file the `;` from the following lines:

```
extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_interbase.dll
```

And if I refresh the page now the error I receive is:

> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\projtesting\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 124

In order to see if the credentials from the database were fine I opened it on the software `SQL Manager 2008 Lite for Interbase and Firebird`, and it was ok.
Any ideas of what's going wrong?

Comment: `That usually means that the table 'categories' doesn't exists..which isn't true.` is a theory at best. Anyways, try seeing what `print_r($db->get('categories'));` gets for you.

Comment: Also, tables are case sensitive in Firebird when quoted, I don't know codeigniter, but it might be quoting table names. You might want to try `CATEGORIES` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Codeigniter 3 (dbdriver = ibase)

```
$db['firebird'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'sysdba',
    'password' => 'masterkey',
    'database' => 'c:/database.GDB',
    'dbdriver' => 'ibase',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'ANSI',
    'dbcollat' => 'NONE',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```